# Having trouble writing a method in C, including pointers and types

Tags: c, shell, pointers, gcc, compiler-errors

I am writing a basic program in C that calculates the average, standard deviation, and median of 5 different grades that the user puts into the program. Functions, references, and pointers are used. Seems like I'm on the right track, yet I wrote the standard deviation method like I would have in Java and not C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>


int* get_data(int num_grades);
float calc_average(int num_grades, int grades[]);
void display_average(float ave);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const int MAX_GRADE = 100;
    printf("enter number of grades: ");
    int num_grades;
    scanf("%d", &num_grades);

    int* result = get_data(num_grades);

    if(num_grades == 0)
    {
        printf("no grades to average\n");
    }
    else
    {
        float ave = calc_average(num_grades, result);
        display_average(ave);
        float standarddev = standard_deviation(num_grades, result);
        display_standarddeviation(standarddev);
    }

    free(result);
    return 0;
}

float calc_average(int num_grades, int grades[])
{
    float ave;
    int i;
    int sum = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < num_grades; i++)
    {
        sum += grades[i];
    }
    ave = (float)sum/num_grades;

    return ave;
}

float standard_deviation(int num_grades, int grades[])
{
    float standarddev;
    int i;
    int *formula = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < num_grades; i++)
    {
        formula += pow((grades[i] - calc_average(num_grades, grades[i])), 2);
    }
    float ave = (float)(1/num_grades)*formula;
    standarddev = (float)sqrt(ave);

    return standarddev;     
}


void display_average(float ave)
{
    printf("average: %.2f\n", ave);
}
void display_standarddeviation(float standarddev)
{
    printf("standard deviation: %.2f\n", standarddev);
}

int* get_data(int num_grades)
{
    int* a;
    a = malloc(num_grades * sizeof(int));
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < num_grades; i++)
    {
        printf("enter a grade: ");
        int grade;
        scanf("%d", &grade);
        if(grade <= 100)
        {
            a[i] = grade;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("grade needs to be > 0 and <= 100\n");
            i--;
        }
    }

    return a;
}
```

When I compile this program, as I'm writing it in Secure Shell Client, and compile it using gcc -g -c grades2.c, then I get this error message:

```
grades2.c:49: error: conflicting types for âstandard_deviationâ
grades2.c:27: note: previous implicit declaration of âstandard_deviationâ was here
grades2.c: In function âstandard_deviationâ:
grades2.c:56: warning: passing argument 2 of âcalc_averageâ makes pointer from integer without a cast
grades2.c:35: note: expected âint *â but argument is of type âintâ
grades2.c:56: error: invalid operands to binary + (have âint *â and âdoubleâ)
grades2.c:58: error: invalid operands to binary * (have âfloatâ and âint *â)
grades2.c: At top level:
grades2.c:69: warning: conflicting types for âdisplay_standarddeviationâ
grades2.c:28: note: previous implicit declaration of âdisplay_standarddeviationâ was here
```

These are basic errors that I believe can easily be fixed, but since it's so easy to make typos and typing errors in Secure Shell Client, I have a hard time finding out which one is which. Oh, and it doesn't specify where to put the replacement error fixes like the IDE. Since I am using the Math header, after I manage to compile it successfully with your input, then I'll say gcc -o grades2.exe grades2.o -lm, with -lm meaning I'm compiling the program with the math header.

May you please help me fix the errors.

Comment: what is `int *formula`? why are you declaring it as a pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give `0`

```
(1/num_grades) * formula
```

change it to

```
1.0 / num_grades * formula
```

the previous, would take integer division, assuming that `abs(num_grades) > 1` then it will be always `0`.

Or a better way would be

```
((float)formula) / num_grades);
```

and instead of casting `sqrt` to `float` use `sqrtf`.

A closer look to your code, reveals something very strange, you declared `formula` as

```
int *formula;
```

then the `+=` operator in the subsequent code is not working as you think, a correct version of the function would be

```
float standard_deviation(int num_grades, int grades[])
{
    float standarddev;
    int i;
    float formula = 0.0f;
    float average = calc_average(num_grades, grades);
    for (i = 0; i < num_grades; i++)
    {
        formula += powf((grades[i] - average), 2);
    }
    float ave = formula / num_grades;
    standarddev = sqrtf(ave);

    return standarddev;
}
```

and you need either a prototype for the `standard_deviation()` function before `main()` or move the whole function definition before `main()`.

Otherwise, what **juanchopanza** you will happen too.

Comment: How do I fix the last two errors?                                                           grades2.c: In function âstandard_deviationâ:
grades2.c:58: warning: passing argument 2 of âcalc_averageâ makes pointer from integer without a cast
grades2.c:37: note: expected âint *â but argument is of type âintâ

Comment: I will fix the answer... Don't compute average in the `for` loop, besides you are passing the i-th value which is an `int` and `calc_average` is expecting a `int` pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the problems pointed out by others, the first error is because you haven't to *declared* `standard_deviation` before it is used in `main()`. This omission means an implicit declaration `int standard_deviation()` is provided. This clashes with the your definition of the same function.

Place this line before `main()`:

```
float standard_deviation(int num_grades, int grades[]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
(float)(1/num_grades)
```

To this:

```
(float)(1)/num_grades
```

Of course, you could simply do `1.0f/num_grades`, but I just wanted to endorse your attention to the order of operations. With `(float)(1/num_grades)`, you are first performing the **integer division** of `1/num_grades` (which most likely yields `0`), and only then casting it to `float` (so you get `0.0`).

Comment: indeed, wihtout the parentheses it would have also worked i.e. `(float)1/num_grades`